# How to check if the id exist in the array? and get the other values

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
[
    {id: 1, name: 'foo'},
    {id: 2, name: 'bar'},
    {id: 3, name: 'test'}
]
```

I want to get check if the data exist and use the other field.
example i want to check if 'id: 1' exist in the string and the 'name:foo'

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: var isPresent = this.productArray.some( (el) => { el.id === 2} ); I saw this code here. it returns boolean, i want to get the other field. not just to identify if it exist.

Comment: You need either `Array.propotype.filter` or new `Array.prototype.find`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find object by id in an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Array.propotype.filter`

```js
var list=[
    {id: 1, name: 'foo'},
    {id: 2, name: 'bar'},
    {id: 3, name: 'test'}
]

const result = list.filter(data => data.id == 2);

console.log(result);
```